# How to get my "Register Now!" Link's to line up at the bottom using CSS

Tags: css

I have this codepen of a pricing table, but I'm unable to get the "register now!" links to line up at the bottom.

http://codepen.io/geirman/pen/brsLm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my version: http://cdpn.io/lezBL

I added

```
position: relative;
```

to #pricing-group then positioned absolutely the links. You could also add padding-bottom to .item in order to prevent overlapping.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that is a little better than the previous as it's more RWD capable. Now I just need to figure out how to get the link to center at the bottom as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a height to your ul will cause them to line up. Here's my version of your paste...

[Codepen](http://cdpn.io/LyDhv)

I just added the class `.brbcoding` to your `ul` and gave it a height of `250px;`